# pandoc listings not mono space font

Tags: fonts, listings, pandoc

I am using pandoc 1.19.2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 to generate a PDF with markdown. I am wondering why my code listing are not rendered in a mono space font.

I defined `monofont: "Ubuntu Mono"` in the YAML header with no effect. What did I mess up? Isn't it be the default to render code samples in mono space?

My header in at the top of the Markdown file is this:

```
---
title:  'Title'
author:
- My name
date: \today
link-citations: true
lang: de-DE
geometry: a4paper, margin=3cm
mainfont: "Palatino"
sansfont: "Roboto Condensed"
monofont: "Ubuntu Mono"
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
numbersections: true
codeBlockCaptions: true
...
```

My compiling command looks like this `pandoc -V breakurl -V hyphens=URL --listing -o doc.pdf doc.md` and does not give an error or a warning.

My Markdown it this:

```
relevant), müssen vor der Berechnung berücksichtigt werden [DIENER2011, S. 10].


~~~{#spheresdf caption="SDF einer Kugel; p ist der Messpunkt, s ist der Radius.[QUILEZ]" }
float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s ){
    return length(p)-s;
}
~~~
```

My in my output PDF the code block is rendered like in the screen shot:
[image]

(The closing square bracket in front of "SDF" is also undesired.)
I'm new to pandoc and totally overwhelmed with latex. Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Without the `--listing` flag the font in the PDF is mono space but doesn't show the caption anymore.

Comment: Hi ǝlpoodooɟƃuooʞ and welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please elaborate a bit more, how your workflow looks, post excerpts of your code and maybe a screenshot of the result? That would help others to help you!

Comment: Hi @TobiBS, I added my header and a screen shot. Thank you

Comment: Related: [Is there a good reason for lstlistings code to look so ugly by default?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/200153)